# Let $p=\overline {abcd}$ be a prime number. Prove that the polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ has no rational roots.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I found this question in a video of the Cheenta Channel which I will link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fi_WOOveig) for reference. It has been marked as a *Simple yet Challenging problem* in the end.

Here are my initial thoughts on the matter:

Let $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $\overline {abcd}=p$ is a prime number.

Therefore $P(10)=p$

We can readily see that $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ where $a\neq 0$.

I tried to do it using the contrapositive assumption.I assumed that the polynomial has a rational root suppose $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ and $n\neq 0$ and it is in lowest form, so

$P(x)=(nx-m)Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ which is true for all real $x$. On putting $x=10$ we see that

$P(10)=p=(10n-m)Q(10)$

And since $m$ and $n$ are integers which imply $(10n-m)$ is also an integer. And it must be $1$ since a $P(10)$ is a prime number. According to ***Rational Root Theorem*** which states:

Each rational solution $x = \frac{p}{q}$, written in lowest terms so that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, satisfies:

$p$ is an integer factor of the constant term, and
$q$ is an integer factor of the leading coefficient.

Therefore, $\left.m\right\rvert d$ and $\left.n\right\rvert a$ and the only combination working to make $(10n-m)=1$ is $m=9,n=1$ which tells us that the root is $9$. But it can not be possible since this cubic equation has positive integral coefficients and thus any positive root is not a possibility. We reach a contradiction.

Is there any flaw in this solution? If so please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: When you deduce that $10n-m=1$, you assume, but haven't proven that $Q(10)$ is an integer, perhaps due to implicitly assuming without proving that $Q$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: Check out [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials))

Comment: 1) The claim of "And it must be 1" is not true. You forgot the case of $(10n-m) = -1$, and of $Q(10) = \pm 1, (10n-m) = \pm p$   $\quad$ 2) The claim of "the root is 9" is also not true. It could be $-9$. How can we reject this? $\quad$ (The lack of awareness of the $\pm$ also brings into question if you truly understand how to apply RRT. Yes I know it could just be an "oversight". )

Comment: Hello there. I admit I did not go over the $Q(10)=+1$ part and thus will reframe my question and for the root, you can verify that the case I took was $(10n-m)=1$ which gave me the only solution which was $(m,n)=(9,1)$ and I might have missed some pairs for I ask apologies from my behalf. Thank you for your input @Calvin Lin.

Comment: To clarify, do you understand what my second point is about? That's a bigger gap here.

Comment: Let me correct a small error in one of your deductions, which may be of no importance. Since $d$ is the last digit of a prime, $d \in \{1,3,7,9 \}$.

Comment: Thank you @YNK and yes I do understand your second point . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have taken the main step. Let's assume the polynomial has a rational root. So, the polynomial is reducible over the rational numbers. Since $p$ is a prime number and no prime number divides all the coefficients $a,b,c,$ and $d$, by [this lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)), we may assume:
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=(mx+n)(ex^2+fx+g),$$
where $m,n,e,f,$ and $g$ are integers. WLOG, we can assume $m,n>0$ because $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ cannot have any positive roots (note $\frac{-n}{m}$ is a root).

Now, on the one hand, we must have:
$$9\geq a=me \implies 9\geq m\\ 9\geq d=gn \implies 9\geq n,$$

and on the other hand:

$$p=1000a+100b+10c+d=(10m+n)(100e+10f+g),$$
which is a contradiction because $p>1000>99\geq 10m+n>1$ while $p$ is a prime number.
Therefore, the polynomial has no rational roots.

Comment: Thank you So much for your help. It is appreciated.